# How to update chat room with PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have an issue displaying messages from my database. My site has a simple chat room which was working perfectly when reading/writing to a textfile. I am now trying to link it to a database with a table called `messages`. Whilst I am writing to the table OK, messages are not being displayed on the screen.

By using POSTMAN, I know that I am successfully talking to the backend because when I run a request - `{"state":1,"text":["Welcome all users!"]}` is returned, which is the last message I had typed, and the `json echo ($log)` is working.

Apart from an `updateChat()` function (posted below) I have a function titled `getState()` which gets the current state of the chat (number of lines, whether new lines added).

Since my SQL queries seem to be working fine, is there an issue with my `updateChat()` or `()getState` function?

Admittedly, I have never built a chatroom before and I am a bit stuck on where to go next.

Thanks for any help or advice!

```
****chat.js****

//Updates the chat
function updateChat() {
    if (!instanse) {
        instanse = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: {
                'function': 'update',
                'state': state,
                'file': file
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.text) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                        $('#chat-area').append($( data.text[i] + "</p>"));
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
                instanse = false;
                state = data.state;
            }
        });
    } else {
        setTimeout(updateChat, 1500);
    }
}
```

```
process.php

 case('getState'):
        $lines = "SELECT messageBody, timeSent, nickname FROM message ORDER BY timeSent";
        $log['state'] = count($lines);
        break;

    case('update'):
        $state = $_POST['state'];

        $lines = "SELECT messageBody, timeSent, nickname FROM message ORDER BY timeSent";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $lines);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $message = $row['messageBody'];
                $time = $row['timeSent'];
                $nickname = $row['nickname'];
            }
        }

        $count = count($lines);
        if ($state == $count) {
            $log['state'] = $state;
            $log['text'] = false;
        } else {
            $text = array();
            $log['state'] = $state + count($lines) - $state;

            $text[] = $message = str_replace("\n", "", $message);
        }

        $log['text'] = $message;     
        break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try catching errors with ajax, if there are, show us.

regardless,

```
$('#chat-area').append($( data.text[i] + "</p>"));
```

this will not work. try this:

```
$('#chat-area').append("<p>" + data.text[i] + "</p>");
```

Comment: ````$('#chat-area').append("<p>" + data.text[i] + "</p>");```` worked! Messages are now being displayed, although every letter is on one line and its displaying the same message over and over until a new input is entered. Any ideas?

Comment: data.text is a string instead of array of strings